# ASP.NET: Write a table (and checkboxes) to a word document

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing an ASP.NET Application in c# and I'm trying to write a table to a word document.

I use currently the following code to write to a word doc:

```
        string strContent = "This content goes to the word document";
        string attach = "attachment; filename=wordtest.doc";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";

        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attach);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(strContent);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
```

Now, my question is if anyone knows how I can write a table to a word document?

And second question is if anyone knows how to write  checkboxes to a word doc (like you copy it from a website and paste it in word)

Thanks in advance!

Killerwes

Answer (score 1):

Word can recognise HTML. So you can simply write any HTML to MS WORD with Response.Write(); Method. Here is code sample.

```
string strBody = "<html>" +

            "<body>" + 

                "<div>Your name is: <b>" + txtName.Text + "</b></div>" +

                "<table width="100%" style="background-color:#cfcfcf;"><tr><td>1st Cell body data</td><td>2nd cell body data</td></tr></table>" +

                "Ms Word document generated successfully." +

            "</body>" +

            "</html>";

        string fileName = "MsWordSample.doc";

        // You can add whatever you want to add as the HTML and it will be generated as Ms Word docs

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Type", "application/msword");

        Response.AppendHeader ("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+ fileName);

        Response.Write(strBody);
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know you could use HTML tags! Do you happen to know how you can disable a checkbox? I tried disabled="disabled" but that didn't work

Comment: i did not ever try to disable any control and save it  on MS WORD. But you can google it. But i can tell you that you can save html to MS WORD and MS Excel.